# Outlook 2007 rule not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have created a rule that deletes a mail when I'm in Cc or sent to me.

Rule:

Apply this rule after the message arrives
Where my name is in the Cc box
  and sent to Firsname Lastname
permanently delete it
  and stop processing more rules

The rule deletes the mail when I'm in Cc but it doesn't delete the mail when I'm both in To and Cc.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is by design.  The rule will be processed if the e-mail is not directly intended for the user.  Since the user is in the 'To' box, the rule was ignored.